# Gitlab-CI and Pipelines: How to Trigger a Pipeline Based on a Merged Branch Event?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a need to auto-deploy our projects to various server instances at the time their corresponding branches are merged back to the develop branch.

I am uncertain how to address this use case using gitlab and pipelines, etc. Since it is triggered by the merge event, I don’t know for sure how to 1) listen for those events, and 2) where/how to capture the steps (currently manual bash scripts) to perform the deployment activities and post-deployment (e.g. starting containers, etc.) activities.

I am basically familiar with AutoDevOps, but I do not need anything to fancy for the time being. We are not using Kubernetes and my understanding is that you need Kubernetes for AutoDevOps.

I would grateful for any general or even specific guidance on how to proceed. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab handles that for you automatically, you just need to define a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` under the root of your project, and specify the stages and scripts.

Refer:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/